# Communication between docker-compose and other images

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-network

I have this architecture:
- 1 docker component running nginx on the host's port 80
- app with 2 services: one node and one mongodb

the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./back-end/
    container_name: "app-back-end"
    volumes:
      - ./back-end/:/usr/src/dance-app-back
      - /usr/src/app-back/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3050"
    links:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.2.15
    ports:
      - "3100:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongodb:/data/db
```

The nginx config file

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location /back_1 {
        #proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:5050/;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5050/;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

The nginx container seems not to be able to reach the port 3000 on the host.
What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to reach to your application server by directly connecting on port 3000 on the host ?  Your nginx config has a proxy pass on port 5050, shouldn't it be 3000 ?

Any specific reason for not integrating nginx in the same compose file as your app ?

Comment: I put the nginx in a separate dockerfile so I can just update the nginx conf file when I have a new website to serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have port 3000 on your host and would like to map it to your container port, than you need to do that in your docker-compose file

Change:

```
backend:
    build: ./back-end/
    container_name: "app-back-end"
    volumes:
      - ./back-end/:/usr/src/dance-app-back
      - /usr/src/app-back/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongodb
```

Then you can link nginx to your container that you want to proxy pass to.

Add to your compose file:

```
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:1.13.1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    links:
      - backend:backend
```

And then in your nginx file mention the name of your application container that you would like to proxy to with the port of that container that is open.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location /back_1 {
        proxy_pass http://backend:3000/;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Instead of the IP of the container inyour nginx, you can link the container name and the nginx config and docker will resolve those IPs for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try it in a bit. But just one question: by putting the nginx in the compose file alongside the other services I will have to restart the whole setup when I add a new website, no?
I put the nginx in a separate dockerfile so I can just update the nginx conf file when I have a new website to serve

Comment: In case you update your Nginx config, only nginx service/container will get re-created. Rest of the containers/services will have no impact. It's ideal to integrate everything in a single compose file whether you are deploying it on one host or multiple host.

Comment: @viveky4d4v got it! thanks again. Just to dig deeper, my issue might come from the fact that I didn't specify my nginx container's network as external network in my docker-compose file. Right?

Comment: You don't need an external network if you are on a single host. All services defined in compose file are reachable to each other by their service names.

Comment: Yes I understood that. But what if a service is running alone inside its own dockerfile, and we need to access it from other services running inside their docker-compose files?